# Как убрать лишние слеши в адресной строке на сайте Word Press?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WP, он поступил нам на доработку, то есть создавался не нами.
У него есть проблема, что при вводе условного site.ru/////catalog он не редиректит на site.ru/catalog, а переходит на страницу, но оставляет в строке лишние /
Пробовали любые правила в .htaccess прописывать, что на просторах интернета смогли найти - ничего не работает. Кэш сбрасывали, тоже никак
Подскажите, пожалуйста, или направьте в какую-нибудь сторону
Если нужно что-то сбросить - без проблем

Comment: Если никакие правила в .htaccess не работают, то, может быть, сайт на nginx? :)

Comment: ВП по дефолту делает такие редиректы. Значит ищи где поломано (плагины или тема).